# Old O level question regarding percentage error - is the wording strange, is my reading ability at fault or is it just a typo?

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic

This is an old O level exam question (O&C) on trigonometry and reads as follows:

In Jones's book of mathematical tables, which are torn, the sines of angles near $65^o$ were missing. Jones looked up $\sin 55^o$ and $\sin 75^o$ and thought that if he took their arithmetic mean he would have the right answer. Using your tables, find his percentage error.

Solution gives $2.96\%$

Using first tables, then calculator for check, my initial working, to 4 s.f. was as follows:

$$\sin 55^o = 0.8192$$
$$\sin 75^o = 0.9659$$
$$\sin 65^o = 0.9063$$
$$arithmetic\ mean = \frac{0.8192 + 0.9659}{2} = 0.8926$$
$$\%error = \frac{0.9063 - 0.8926}{0.9063}\times 100 = 1.52\%$$
This, as you can no doubt see, does not agree with answer in text.
The only way I can get an answer any where near that of the text is to proceed as follows:
$$\%\: error\:of\: \sin55^o\:from\:\sin65^o = \frac{0.9063 - 0.8192}{0.9063}\times 100 = -9.611\%$$
$$\%\: error\:of\: \sin75^o\:from\:\sin65^o = \frac{0.9659 - 0.9063}{0.9063}\times 100 = 6.576\%$$
and
$$|-9.611\% + 6.567\%| = 3.04\%$$
I should repeat answers given here have been rounded so will not be exact.
However, if this is correct, and it's not that close to the answer given, I'm not sure what I've calculated to get correct answer. Moreover, if this is correct, what did I calculate originally?

As always, many thanks in advance for any advice given.

I would like to add that this question is taken from an old O level book and not from a specific examination paper so a typo is possible.

Comment: Your answer of $1.52$% is correct. Books sometimes have errors.

Comment: Just had an after-thought: 3.04/2 = 1.52. Does it therefore follow that the mean of the errors is the error of the mean?

Comment: You are right. +1 for finding an error in a text.

Comment: @GR L: Identically, if$\;0 < a < b < c$, then
$$
\frac
{
{\Large{
\frac{a-b}{b}
+
\frac{c-b}{b}
}}
}
{\large{2}}
=
\frac
{
{\Large{
\frac{a+c}{2}
-
b
}}
}
{\large{b}}
$$

Comment: @quasi Many thanks. I’ve learned more here than I can say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's eliminate all of the numbers for a while.

> In Jones's book of mathematical tables, which are torn, the sines of
> angles near $x$ were missing. Jones looked up $\sin(x-h)$ and
> $\sin(x+h)$, and thought that if he took their arithmetic mean
> he would have the right answer. Using your tables, find his percentage
> error.

So his approximation is

\begin{align}
   \sin x &\approx \frac 12 \left(\sin(x-h) + \sin(x+h)   \right) \\
   &\approx \sin(x) \cos(h) \\
\end{align}

The percentage error is

$$100 \dfrac{\sin(x) - \sin(x) \cos(h)}{\sin(x)} = 100(1 - \cos(h))$$

It's interesting to note that the percentage error does not actually depend of the value of $\sin(x)$

For this problem, $h = 10^\circ = \dfrac{\pi}{18} \text{radians}$.

So the percentage error is

$$100\left(1 - \cos \dfrac{\pi}{18} \right) \approx 1.52\%$$

Comment: That’s a great answer, hadn’t thought of the in that generalised way Many thanks.